# Is it possible to differentiate the Gamma function with product rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gamma-function

I want to differentiate the Gamma function using product rule:

$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x+1)=\frac{d}{dx}x\Gamma(x)$$

$$=x\left(\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x)\right)+\Gamma(x)$$

If $\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x)=F(x),$ then we have

$$F(x+1)=xF(x)+\Gamma(x)$$

I was wondering if there were any possible way to solve for $F(x)$ in terms of $x$ from here.

Another route:

$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x+1/2)=2^{1-2x}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2x)$$

Differentiated both sides and applied product rule.

$$F(x)\Gamma(x+1/2)+F(x+1/2)\Gamma(x)=\sqrt{\pi}(-2\ln(2)2^{1-2x}\Gamma(2x)+2^{1-2x}F(2x))$$

Any way we could make use of these formulas to differentiate the Gamma function?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) might be relevant.

Comment: @Wojowu Nah, I want to do it using product rule.

Comment: The definition of gamma function involves some additional log convexity assumption besides the functional equation. So to differentiate it one must also translate that information properly.

Comment: I also don't really understand what you want when saying "...to solve for $x$ from there". The stated equality holds for all $x$, so it would make no sense to solve it for $x$.

Comment: @Wojowu Fixed it.